# Need Clarification Prot Pally Block+dodge+parry+5% chance for the boss to miss

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I would appreciate someone clarifying the percentages.  For example, my Mastery rating says I block 49% (Okay), which is straightforward.  However, under the "Defense" information it shows my Dodge, Parry and Block percentages.  The Block % here is 54.48%, which is 5% higher than what the Mastery section entails.  **Therefore, my question: is the 54.48%, my Mastery 49% + the 5% chance to miss me?  Or do I need to add the 5% to 54.48% + dodge + parry = 102.4%???**

Comment: I haven't played WoW since a few years but from what i understand it should be 54.48% * 49%, i.e. 0.4552 (chance to get through dodge) * 0.51 (chance to get through block) = 23.22% chance for the opponent to hit you.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the explanation I am looking for.  I just want to know if the 5% "Boss" chance to miss is included in the Block percentage in the Defense Tab?

Answer (score 2):

**54.48% is just your chance to block. It does not include the 5% miss chance.**

Every paladin and warrior has a base chance to block of 5%. Remember that you don't learn mastery until a certain level, so all those low level tanks would otherwise have no way of blocking!

So the 54.48% block listed is the sum of your natural block (5%) and your mastery (49.48%).

---

In summary, your Combat Table Coverage (aka "unhittable") calculation is

```
54.48 (block) + 5 (miss) + X (parry) + Y (dodge)
```

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz /facepalm thanks for the edit

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest reading this thread over at [battle.net](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2489160859) it explains how to break down avoidance and diminishing returns, probably better than anyone here at gaming.se.

From what I know, yes, the base 5% hit from bosses is covered in total avoidance (from the defense tab). That is why you aim for 102.4% cap

> Your total avoidance is worked out by adding it up and if it's more than 102.4%, bosses can't hit you.
>
> It's worth pointing out here, that mobs higher levelled than you have
>   an innately higher chance to hit. It works out to be a 0.2% decrease
>   to each avoidance stat per level above you, so for warriors and
>   Paladins, 0.8% total per level, DKs have 0.6% total per level and
>   druids have 0.4% total per level. However, only shield tanks are ever
>   going to reach unhittable because of how diminishing returns work,
>   since bosses are 3 levels above you, **so you actually need to get your
>   avoidance to add up to 102.4%, not 100%**.

Comment: curious to know why the down vote.